# Expectation of Two Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

The probability of the amount of time taken for a secretary to process a memo independent of others is modeled as an exponential random variable with PDF
$ \\ f_{T}(t) =  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }e ^{-\frac{ t }{ 2 }}$.

Also, the probability of the number of memos that the secretary is assigned daily is modeled as  a Poisson RV with PMF
$$
 P_{N}(k) = \frac{ L^k}{ k! }e^{-L} \mbox{ for all integers }k\ge 0
$$
where $L$ is a positive constant.

What is the total expected amount of time the secretary spends on memos per day?

Comment: The way I interpret the problem is far more complex than I think it should be.  I'm thinking: if A memos arrive, then a of those jobs can take t1 seconds, while the remaining A-a can take t2 to t_inf, so I have to sum over infinite time and possibilities of number of memos; that is after introducing the Binomial RV.

Comment: Another approach to finding the answer: compute the expected waiting time given $m$ memos arrive ($m$ treated as constant). Then compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P_N(k) \mathbb{E}(\mbox{total time}|\mbox{$k$ memos arrive})$. This is an easy calculation, if you know the standard Taylor expansion of the exponential.

Comment: Can you explain how I'd do the first part? (waiting time given m memos arrive)

Comment: My problem is formulating  $\\ P_{T,N}()$  because each memo can take a separate amount of time. If I take the joint PMF as the product since they are independent, using the conditional PMF simply means P_{T,N}(T|N=m) = $P_{N}(m)*P_{T}/P_{N}(m) = P_{T} $ Seems faulty.

Comment: The waiting time for $m$ memos is just their sum. The expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations. So it's just $m$ times the expected waiting time for one memo. $(2m)$.

Comment: You don't really need to formulate $P_{T,N}()$. (I take it $N$ is the number of memos and $T$ is their total time.) And the formula you wrote in your last comment is just not right. In fact, the joint distribution is pretty non-trivial to formulate. (It involves gamma distributions.) Tip: dealing with expectations is often way easier than dealing with explicit distributions or higher moments. Try to deal with them instead of distributions (e.g., pmfs or pdfs) whenever you can.

Comment: The sigma becomes:  $sum_{k=0}^{infty} \left( \frac{ L^k }{ k! }e^{-L}*2k\right)$

Comment: Yes, I ran into the Gamma distribution while looking for a solution. My proposed solution decomposes into the gamma, but I think there's an easier way.

Comment: Okay, well that gives 2L.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made it complicated by considering the time interval between each memo and the fact that a day is not infinite and so on. Thanks for clearing things out.

Comment: The answer 2L presupposes that there are some days when the secretary spends more than 24 hours to process the memos, which seems absurd.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the question is idealized. Do you have a more standardized solution @Did ?

Comment: So suppose 5 memos are assigned to the secretary on a particular day. What is a good estimate for L? I'm guessing L = 5 since the mean is L. @WillNelson

Comment: This depends on the way the memos in excess are treated (abandoned? completed on the next day?). Only you can provide this piece of information.

Comment: Another issue here, is that the time spent on each memo cannot be modeled as an exponential RV, because this means that it may happen that the secretary spends an "infinite amount of time" on some memo. So even looking at a single day, the support is $(0,\bar T)$ and you have a truncated exponential.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos That's all the information provided in the problem. I don't think the memos are allowed to spill over to the next day, so we can say a day is infinite. Doesn't make sense but no conditions were imposed in the problem.

Comment: ...and this is what makes the problem uninteresting, having the obvious answer $2L$. Restricting the total working time  available per day, as I noted, and permitting unfulfilled memos to spill over, as Did mentioned, would make this a really interesting real-world problem.

Comment: Cool, so how would we go about solving such a real-world problem? Assuming predefined conditions.

Comment: @Did, Alecos, My opinion: 1. Did raises a good point. But assuming this is homework of some sort, the answer the questioner is looking for is very likely $2L$, since the question doesn't mention Did's possibility. 2. Regardless how the work is done, as long as no work is abandoned before completion, $2L$ is correct if the "expected work per day" includes all the work spent on the memos arriving in a given day, regardless whether the work is performed that day or some other day. 3. If $2L>1$ day, the work backlog increases without bound and the worker eventually works 24 hours a day forever!

Comment: See why they need to raise the minimum wage?

Comment: @WillNelson Assuming this is homework, is it proper to say given some particular day that H memos were assigned to the secretary, once can assume L (the mean of the number of memos assigned) is H ?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The number of memos is $N$ (I thought that's why you wrote $P_N$.) $N$ is a random variable. You wrote down the distribution of $N$. It's Poisson. The mean of $N$ is $L$, which is some constant. The mean of $N$ doesn't somehow change from day to day. $N$ can assume different values on different days (it's a random variable), but it always has the same mean. To get the vocabulary straight, look at some basic examples in whatever textbook you're using and carefully read over some examples of random variables and expectation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Justify the claim that $N$ and $T$ are independent.  If you haven't shown that for independent $X$ and $Y$, $E(XY) = E(X) E(Y)$ (this step generalizes what I imagine your argument involving sums does), do so now.  Apply the result.

Edit in response to your comment:

You want to know why the value you seek is $E(NT)$.

We have:  $(S|N) = T_1 + T_2 + \cdots T_N$ is the time it takes to process $N$ claims.  Then

$$
  E(S|N) = E(T_1) + E(T_2) + \cdots + E(T_N) = N \cdot E(T)
$$

What is the expectation of that value?

Comment: Yes, I did just that to give E(N) = L and E(T) = 2, so E(LT) = 2L.
But here's my argument: Each memo takes a separate time independent of other, so say n memos are sent, then out of that n, k can take t1 in n choose K ways, and the rest can take t2 and so on.  This requires another construction which isn't giving 2L.

Comment: I can tell you that your construction has an error, but cannot tell you what the problem is unless you write it up.

Comment: My point is: why would it have to be E(NT) since each subset of N can take a different T value? Shouldn't it be to find the number of ways in which all subsets of N can take all values in T? I'm having trouble depicting this mathematically.

Comment: Examine the edit.

Comment: In response to your post:
E(N*E(T)) = E(NT). My question is: why did you factor out the N from the expression to give N.E(T) ?

Comment: Because each $T_i$ is drawn from the same distribution as the original $T$, so $E(T_i) = E(T)$, and there are $N$ of them.

Comment: I think it makes sense now. Since the individual memos take distinct times based on one pdf, their expected value are the same; then one just has to broaden that to the expected value of the memo numbers. My final answer is 2L.

Comment: If I'm asked to find an estimate for L given 5 memos were assigned to the secretary on a specific day, do I just say 5=L since L is the mean of the number of memos assigned?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best estimate you can make with a single sample.

Comment: Okay. Say the problem weren't idealized and a day is not considered to be infinite, then the exponential reduced to a truncated exponential with an upper bound t =  number of hours in a day. How would I go about solving the initial problem?

Comment: You would compute $E(T')$ for a truncated exponential distribution.  You would multiply by $E(L)$.

Comment: Why T' ?  And E(L) is just E of a constant.

Comment: Goodness, are you even trying?  Or are you trying to get me to do your homework for you?

Comment: This stuff was never discussed. I'm trying to learn this personally. Mostly, a topic is mentioned and the rest is up to us to explore. I'm not trying to exploit you; I just want to understand how a real-world problem will be solved. 
My question was, why do you have to take the derivative of T?

Comment: $T'$ isn't the derivative of $T$.  It's just a new random variable for the distribution you introduced.

Comment: Makes sense. I already did that earlier, but it seems too simple since some memos may be stopped midway and/or carried over to the next day and so on.

Comment: If you want to account for carry-over, you want to look into "queuing theory".